# what do I save in cache to run web app in pwa?

Tags: typescript, progressive-web-apps, yarn-v2

I did a lot of research and even managed to make a simple pwa that works with the html. However, I am stuck on how I can manage to save the main application of the website into the cache and how do I manage that the yarn scripts also work on the website? They used typescript for the application

I tried to google and research (I just found basic how to stuff that I already managed to do) and looked at examples of pwa that feature apps. I still don't understand.

Comment: This sounds like a question that _is_ answered in basic how-to's, e.g., [this one on web.dev](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/caching/). If this doesn't help you, please explain more specifically what you tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are very confused and have a problem with separation of concerns.

Yarn, is another npm, manages node modules, which run on the server, not the client. So those would not have anything to do with your client experience.

Caching data and site assets does require some custom work on your part. I like to cache data in IndexedDB and use it as a database. For assets, like HTML, CSS, JS, images, fonts, etc I cache those in service worker cache.

From there you need to create the logic you need to create the best offline experience you can for your users. This means some things may not be available. Others may be available but you need to be synchronized when the device is back online.

Start simple and build from there.